# Pointer to member function of another class

Tags: c++

I have two classes, `CEffect` and `CEffectPool`. A third class `CLevel`, is doing most of the stuff in my code.

In every frame, it checks each `CEffect` in `CEffectPool`, and if it is currently inactive, it disables it.

What I would like to do is to give `CEffect` the pointer to the `CEffectPool` member function called `Destroy()`, so I don't have to check every single `CEffect` by another class whether it shall be destroyed or not.

With this function pointer, `CEffect` would simply call a function, which would destroy it.

Also, I am not talking about destroying in the C++ way (I don't want memory to be freed or to call the destructor).

Here is some code, that i have, but it unfortunately don't work and I am not sure why:

CEffect.h

```
class CEffectPool;
class CEffect {
    public:
        CEffect();
        CEffect(const CEffect& eff);
        CEffect& operator=(const CEffect& eff);
        void Initialize(CEffectPool* pool,
                        ushort id,
                        real x,
                        real y,
                        ushort timer);
        void Frame();
        void Draw();
        bool IsActive() const;
    private:
        CEffectPool* _pool;
        ushort _id;
        CSprite _sprite;
        ushort _anmfrm;
        ushort _timer;
};
void DestroyEffect(CEffectPool* pool,
                   ushort id);
```

CEffect.cpp

```
void CEffect::Frame() {
    if(_timer) {
        --_timer;
        return;
    }
    ++_anmfrm;
    if(_anmfrm == 24) {
        DestroyEffect(_pool,_id);
    }
}
```

CEffectPool.cpp

```
void CEffectPool::Destroy(ushort index) {
    if(index >= _size) {
        return;
    }
    CEffect temporary = _pool[index];
    _pool[index] = _pool[_size-1];
    _pool[_size-1] = temporary;
    --_size;
}
void DestroyEffect(CEffectPool* pool,
                   ushort id) {
    pool->Destroy(id);
}
```

Could you help me with this? What is the best approach to do this?

Comment: Can you clarify what you want with an example of how it would be used? Also telling us how you've tried to solve it would help by giving us a starting point for helping you.

Comment: I have tried it to solve by declaring global function Destroy, which takes CEffectPool by pointer as first parameter and index of the CEffect in CEffectPool as second parameter. CEffect calls this function, which is later defined in CEffectPool.cpp.

Answer (score 1):

If what you are looking for is a pointer to a member function of `CEffect`, then it would be something in the lines:

```
// Assuming the type CEffect is a class with a Destroy() method
// as shown below:
class CEffect {
public:
    void Destroy() { ... };
};

// Declare a pointer-to-member type, for convenience: 
typedef void (CEffect::* DestroyFunc)();
```

Then you declare a member function pointer just like you would with a normal C function pointer:

```
DestroyFunc destroy = &CEffect::Destroy;
```

To call it, it is a bit different then with a C function. You will need a class instance:

```
CEffect * effect = new CEffect(...);

// Call CEffect::Destroy for 'effect':
(effect->*destroy)();
```

Comment: The destroying in my code is nothing else than switching it's position in CEffectPool. So I would like to have pointer to member function of CEffectPool in CEffect.

Comment: Well, just replace `CEffect` with `CEffectPool` ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need a pointer to a method. You already have a pointer to the CEffectPool instance.

You should do like the following code :

```
void CEffect::Frame() 
{
    //...

    if(_anmfrm == 24)
    {
        _pool->Destroy(_id);//you call directly the method of CEffectPool
    }
}
```

`CEffectPool::Destroy` should be public to be used by another object.

Comment: Isn't it a problem that CEffectPool is just predeclared class? CEffect don't know anything about the methods of CEffectPool.

Comment: You have to include the CEffectPool header in the CEffect.cpp